# Select one field and pass it over a pipe to other program

Tags: mysql, bash, pipe

How do I select only one specific field from a query result and pass it over a pipe in clear text to other program, e.g. grep?

```
echo 'SELECT field FROM database.table WHERE id = 10' | mysql | grep something
```

With that command I get a field name on the top, plus have everything anywhere special escaped, e.g. newlines come as `\n` so are other special characters:

```
field
somewhere\n\tsomething\n\tnothing
```

What I need to get is only:

```
somewhere
    something
    nothing
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out these two options do the trick:

```
mysql --silent --raw
```

With `--raw` it doesn't escape anything, and with `--silent` it doesn't print column names.

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine some combination of `sed`, `printf` and `tail` would do the trick.

You can use `tail` to get only the last line (skipping `field`), `sed` to ensure a clean no-argument `printf`-style string, `and`printf` itself to translate the special characters.

I'd start with something like (across multiple lines for readability but you should have it as one command):

```
printf "$(echo 'SELECT field FROM database.table WHERE id = 10'
    | mysql
    | tail -1l
    | sed 's/%/%%/g')"
```

The following transcript offers an example, with dummied up data since I don't run MySQL:

```
pax> printf "$(echo 'heading
...> field\n\twith a %\n\tand 3 lines' | tail -1l | sed 's/%/%%/g')"
field
    with a %
    and 3 lines
```